# Getting name property from package.json with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I would like to know if there is a way in NodeJs to get the name property from my project `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "bendiciones",
    "version": "1.12.0",
    "description": " bendiciones",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
...
}
```

I've tried with

```
import {name} from './package.json';
import {name} from './app.json'
```

but I got the errors:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module './package.json'.
TS2307: Cannot find module './app.json'.
```

I've tried also with:

```
 console.log ('--2>', process.env.npm_package_name);
```

but I get `undefined`

Comment: I'm finding lots of questions with answers when I [search this](/search?q=%5Bnode.js%5D+read+package.json), have you looked at those? What about those answers doesn't work in your situation?

Comment: Are you speaking about your own package.json or package.json belongs to installed packages?

Comment: Which Node version? most versions don't support native `import` statements, and you will need to use `require`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue. As a solution, you should add a custom typing i.e. `json-loader.d.ts` with the content

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using TypeScript, this becomes easy:

```
import pkg from '../path/to/package.json';

pkg.name;
```

It does require the following `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `require` the entire file and choose whichever properties you want:

```
const packageJSON = require("path/to/your/package.json");

console.log(packageJSON.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using pure Javascript with no loaders you will have to load the package.json file manually:

```
import { readFileSync } from "fs";

// ./package.json is relative to the current file
const packageJsonPath = require.resolve("./package.json");

const packageJsonContents = readFileSync(packageJsonPath).toString();

const packageJson = JSON.parse(packageJsonContents);

console.log(packageJson.name);
```

Comment: This is the best answer imho, since it involves minimal magic. The other answers are showing nice tricks to make this simpler, but your approach will work under all conditions, whether using typescript or Webpack etc, or not. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

I also want to do the same and here's the code that worked. Since it uses `require` to load the `package.json`, it works regardless of the current working directory.

```js
var packageFile = require('./package.json');
console.log(packageFile);
```

**A warning:**

> Be careful not to expose your `package.json` to the client, as it means that all your dependency version numbers, build and test commands and more are sent to the client.
>   If you're building server and client in the same project, you expose your server-side version numbers too.
>   Such specific data can be used by an attacker to better fit the attack on your server.